# Mobile website push notifications - after session over?

Tags: javascript, html, mobile-website, web-push, push-api

I know this question pops up quite a bit but it is always in different context...

I need to create a mobile website and wondering if it is possible to ask the user's permission to push notifications after the user closed the site session and moved on... like Facebook's Desktop notifications but on the mobile...
Is there a way to ask the user for this general permission and push notifications from a server regardless if the user is on your mobile website or not?
Like native apps do...

Cheers
Ajar

Just to explicitly clarify - this is NOT about phonegap or any other cross-compiling, neither it is referring to on-site in session sockets real-time communication.

Comment: I believe this is what you're looking for: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/push-notifications-on-the-open-web?hl=en (Although I have no idea how widely supported that is, especially on mobile devices. You may need to experiment)

Comment: Hi Dave, thank you for responding. I saw this link but it relates only to chrome which have an impressive 40% market-share of mobile browsers  but still you loose 60% in the process...
https://www.netmarketshare.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=1&qpcustomb=1
Is there a wider html5 standard or polyfill for push notifications for all browsers?

Comment: I suspect that Chrome's attempt will migrate into (or be replaced by) a standard, given enough time. But it looks like for now it is the best available. Since this is entirely new functionality (rather than a simple convenience around existing features), you won't be able to polyfill it.

Comment: Got it Dave - thank you!

Comment: What’s described at https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/push-notifications-on-the-open-web is already a W3C standard. The spec is at http://w3c.github.io/push-api/ and Firefox is already implementing it, and it will eventually get implemented in Edge as well. More info at MDN at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Push_API/Using_the_Push_API

Answer (score 1):

Chrome supports this functionality on Android as well as desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/push-notifications-on-the-open-web

On iOS this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

On iOS, this is not possible.

You can implement notifications on the desktop version of Safari, however those won't work on the mobile (iOS) version.

Only native iOS apps (which would include hybrid apps in this case) allow push notifications on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can send **off-site push notifications without an app** using the W3C **Push API**.

However the only **mobile** browser that supports them is **Chrome on Android** (while most desktop browsers already support them). If you want to build everything from scratch I suggest reading [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/push-notifications-on-the-open-web). However it's a lot of work: consider third party services like [Pushpad](http://pushpad.xyz) (I am the founder).